# Python list is converted into integer

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

While testing code some errors appeared - after a mathematical operation, a list 'shrinks' down to itself's last item

In the Python 3.3 interpreter it works fine...

```
a = [a + b for a, b in zip(a, b)]
```

I'm using this code to add some list items

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [2, 3, 2]
```

this works fine and returns

```
>>> a
[3, 5, 5]
>>> b
[2, 3, 2]
```

Then I wrote a class to handle more lists:

```
class Vector:

    def __init__(self, name = '', vector = []):
        self.__name = name
        self.__vector = vector


    def add_row_to_scalar_multiple(self, vector):
        self.__vector = [self.__vector + vector.__vector for self.__vector, vector.__vector in zip(self.__vector, vector.__vector)]


    def __str__(self):
        vec = ('{0} = {1}'.format(self.__name, self.__vector))
        formatted_vec = vec.replace(',', '')
        return formatted_vec
```

When running the code with the same lists as above, one list is reduced to a single integer

```
vec_a = Vector('a', [1, 2, 3])
vec_b = Vector('b', [2, 3, 2]) 

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [2, 3, 2]

vec_b.add_row_to_scalar_multiple(vec_a)


a = 3
b = [3, 5, 5]
```

I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, so anyone could please help??

Comment: This isn't your problem, but your `__init__` has a mutable default argument which is going to cause you headaches later.

Comment: Well, `a` is becoming `3` because you are assigning that value to it.

Comment: `for self.__vector, vector.__vector in` - what?

Comment: And you don't need two leading underscores for the attributes. One should be enough.

Comment: To expand on what @Wooble said, you should change `vector=[]` in your `__init__` definition to `vector=None`, and have `if vector is None: vector = []`.  This will remove the headaches mentioned (and I promise you will have headaches if you don't do this).

Comment: @Wooble: That's only a problem if `self.__vector` is mutated. Another option would be to use an empty tuple, `()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> a = [a + b for a, b in zip(a, b)]
> ```

You should not be using "a, b" for the iteration variables, they are not the same things as the original lists, and this led you to make the mistake of thinking they should always be the same as the things you're zipping.

It should be for example `a = [aa + bb for aa, bb in zip(a, b)]`

And then in converting it to your class, you would have seen, instead of this:

> ```
> self.__vector = [self.__vector + vector.__vector
>                  for self.__vector, vector.__vector
>                  in zip(self.__vector, vector.__vector)]
> ```

You should have this:

> ```
> self.__vector = [aa + bb
>                  for aa, bb
>                  in zip(self.__vector, vector.__vector)]
> ```

Also, your function should *probably* be called `__iadd__`, but that's beside the point.

On an unrelated note:

> ```
>    self.__vector = vector
> ```

This line has two problems. For one thing, it's just storing a reference to the list that is passed in (which may not be what you want). The much bigger issue is that your default `vector = []` argument is the same list every time. Mutable types for defaults should be avoided unless you know what you're doing. I would suggest `self.__vector = list(vector)`.

Comment: So using self.__vector, vector.__vector multiple times in the statement caused the problems?

Answer (score 6):

```
self.__vector = [self.__vector + vector.__vector for self.__vector, vector.__vector in zip(self.__vector, vector.__vector)]
```

See that? You're assigning values to `self.__vector, vector.__vector` in the loop `for self.__vector, vector.__vector in zip(self.__vector, vector.__vector)`.